# Asterisk IVR - input variable and go to an outbound URL

Tags: asterisk, url

I have an Asterisk outbound IVR system set up, and I'd like it to talk to my LAMP stack on a different server. I've set up the PHP end to receive data from the IVR server and record it in MySQL, but I can't figure out how to get the Asterisk end to go to the php URL and I haven't figured out yet how to input a variable into the IVR script from the PHP server.

In my current setup, a PHP script authenticates to the asterisk server, and then sends an outbound call command. The outbound call then goes to a call script listed in extensions.conf. My first question is, how do I send a variable through the URL into extensions.conf, such as the name of the person I'm calling? Do I have to create a .call file with the name every time and FTP it into the Asterisk server?

At certain points in the call script, I'd like Asterisk to open up a URL (of the format 192.168.123.123/ivr/record?question=$question&answer=$answer). It doesn't need to process any data from the URL, it's just telling PHP to integrate the IVR call data into the existing LAMP system. Is there a way for me to do that? And if so, how do I do that?

```
<?php 
//IVR controller on the PHP server. Our employee clicks a button and IVR makes a call.
//...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $call_url = $asterisk_server ."/rawman" .
    "?action=originate&channel=". $sip_trunk . $outbound_prefix .    
    $next_call['phone_number'] . 
    "&extension=$extension&context=outgoingIVR&priority=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $auth_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$urlresult = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//...
?>

;Extensions.conf on the IVR server
[outgoingIVR]
exten => 500,1,Wait(0.25)
exten => 500,n,Answer()
exten => 500,n,Wait(0.75)
exten => 500,n,Festival("Hi. This is company name. We are the guys that do the thing.")
exten => 500,n, Goto(question1,s,1)

[question1]
exten => s,1(start),Wait(0.5)
;@TODO: read variable into festival here.
exten=> s,n, festival("Are You Jane Doe")
   same => n,WaitExten()
exten => 1,1, Goto(are-you-sure,s,1)
;@TODO: save yes response here
exten => 2,1, goto(get-jane,s,1)
;@TODO: save no response here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for [func_curl](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+curl).  It may not be built on your system by default but the page I referenced has instructions to build it.  Here's the example provided:

```
exten => s,1,Set(foo=${CURL(http://somewhere.com/somepage.html?x=5&y=4)})
```